# Run pm2 with super user access

Tags: node.js, hapi.js, pm2

I have a node app that i want to run with root access, I've tried running it with this

```
sudo pm2 start <my-app> --watch
```

The reason i really i need it is because in my code there is a command to create a new folder its still failed, just for information i am using hapijs framework inside my node app,

It gave me this error

```
errno: -13,
0|<my-app> |   code: 'EACCES',
0|<my-app> |   syscall: 'mkdir',
0|<my-app> |   path: 'uploaded_file/122334455/' }
```

I've tried running pm2 with super user, modifying `.pm2` directory with 777 but no luck.

How should i do to fix this issue?

Thankyou.

Comment: you need to few more things in question as it's little unclear what location are you trying to create that folder, `it is because in my code there is a command to create a new folder` by command  do you here mean _mkdirSync from **fs** module_ and why are you trying to give 777 permission to .pm2 folder are you trying to create directory in .pm2 folder. ?

Comment: @vinitpayal that is true, i use mkdirSync, well thats what i got after searching similar issue

Comment: ok and at what location are you trying to create that directory  still not getting giving 777 to .pm2 folder as this folder is for storing pm2 configuration only ?

Comment: @vinitpayal /my-app/uploaded_file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First giving 777 permission is not a good solution as it will expose your user uploaded content to read by anyone and over that giving 777 permission to ***.pm2 directory*** doesn't make any sense as it only stores configurations for pm2 even if you want to go with giving 777 permission you should change permission of `/my-app/uploaded_files/`.

Better approach here would be to allow owner of *pm2 process* to write to `/my-app/uploaded_files/` folder which can be done by two ways :-

- By creating a **user group** and adding **pm2 process owner** in that group([create user group and adding user in group in Linux](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-add-user-to-group/)) and then changing `/my-app/uploaded_files/` directory's owner to **group_name** you have created using `sudo chown -R :group_name /my-app/uploaded_files/`
- By changing owner of `/my-app/uploaded_files/` folder to user pm2 using `sudo chown -R user_name: /my-app/uploaded_files/`

Both of above methods work work but using **group** should be more preferred as using that in future if we want to allow permission to one more user to same directory we can just add one more user to the group and everything else would be same.

Hope it clarifies let me know in comments if anything needs more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out i have to modify the permission on my destination folder which is `uploaded_file` thanks to @vinitpayal for inspiring me to come to this work around